# How to select everything that does not start with s number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to find all values that do not start with a number

I have tried this query, but not sure if the REGEXP is correct. This seem to be returning any value the does not contains a number

```
SELECT * FROM table where address NOT REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this fixed the issue

```
SELECT * FROM table where address NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL if you try to convert a string to a number then it will start from the beginning taking the digits and convert as much as possible.

If a string does not start with a number then the result is `0`.

```
select * from your_table
where address * 1  = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/48189)

<sub>You can use explicit conversion with `cast(str_column as unsigned)` or implicit conversion by using a mathematical operator like `* 1`</sub>